# jQuery: How to check, if list elements have not the same attribute like my variable?

Tags: jquery, list, selector

I have a list and every list element li has a class attribute. The list elements belonging to the same issue have the same class. There is a slider where only one list element can appear and i have a counter that gives me back the index of the current slide.

And there is another list with special content and i wanna hide the list elements that have not the same class like the current slide elements class.

Here is the code:

```
var start_count = 0; //increases when clicking on next button
var current_slide_clid = $('.bxslider li').eq(start_count).attr('class'); // give me the class attribute of the currently displayed slide element
$('#clips li').attr('class').not(current_slide_clid).css('display', 'none'); // #clips is the other list with list elements i wanna hide
```

but this one gives me back the following error:

> TypeError: $(...).attr(...).not is not a function

I tried some other selectors like:

```
$('#clips li:not([current_slide_clid])');
```

or:

```
$('#clips li').attr('class').not(current_slide_clid);
```

but they all didnt work. So how can I select the list elements that dont match with my current slide's class? Any Ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be

```
$('#clips li').not('.'+current_slide_clid);
```

or

```
$('#clips li:not(.' + current_slide_clid + ')');
```

`$('#clips li').attr('class')` return the class attribute of the element which is a string value, it does not have the `.not()` method